# BCP -- create file only if stored procedure returns data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bcp

I have a problem where empty files are created with the bcp command when used with queryout option.

```
    DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(500);  
    SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp '  
                            + '"Exec Migration.usp_GenerateXml"'  
                            + ' queryout ' + @FileLocation  
                            + @FileName 
                            + ' -c -T -S ' + @ServerName ;  
   SELECT  @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute';
   EXECUTE Migration..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd;
```

Is there a way to actually create the file only if there are any rows returned by the stored procedure?

I would prefer not to call the procedure two times, i.e first time to inspect and second time with the bcp command

Comment: Maybe you could write the results to a temp table and then check to see if count(1) > 0 before you write to file. This may be easier using Powershell as well.

Comment: update your sp to push an output then check if output contains a row then execute bcp.

Comment: I have used both the above suggestions. I stored the results inside a temp table within the Migration_usp_GenerateXml and moved the bcp command inside this procedure with an IF statement to check if count > 0,  I did a bcp with just with the -out option directly from the temp table. Then I also modified the procedure to push an Output parameter to signal if a file was created since the calling procedure needs to know if a file was created